# How to distinguish between new and returning anonymous Drupal users?

Tags: php, drupal, session, cookies, registration

Is there an easy way (or a module) in Drupal to distinguish between anonymous users who have never created an account versus those who are returning but are not currently logged in?

For non-returning (ie, completely new) users, I'd like to have a front page that is very streamlined and focused on registration as the call-to-action. However, if someone is a returning user but not currently logged in, I'd like to present a lot more information on the front page and have login as the main call-to-action. I realize both pages would still need to have both login and register options available, I just want to make the focus significantly different between the two.

Comment: You could try setting a cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning Drupal users have a cookie. New users don't, yet. You could poke around in Drupals session information such as

```
$_SESSION['pirate'] = array('hello' => 'Ahoy!');
```

However, Drupals offers little help and leaves a lot to the one implementing (which, obviously is far too often ignored). Things like garbage collection, sessions trough ip-changes and so on.

For that, I would advice a small but usefull API module, wich simply wraps around the far too-low-level session-API in Drupal-core and makes it nice to work with: [session api](http://drupal.org/project/session_api).

Note that, since you asked this question on stackoverflow and not on *webmasters* I assumed you are looking for a way to use this in a module you are developing. Session API offers module developers with an API, it offers no turnkey no-php-needed solution.

Comment: I'll check out the Session API module in more detail. Thanks! I'm also looking into the Known User Role module, which also looks promising: http://drupal.org/project/known_user_role